# How can I show multiple datas in MUI Table or DataGrid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Does anyone can give me some example or hints to create a table like this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adMd5.png)

I know the basic of MUI table but I do not know how I can group up the datas like this.
Thank You

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60916880/material-ui-how-to-set-grid-element-to-span-3-rows-vertically

Comment: I guess no... What I want is how I can let 2 or more data with same key that can combine into one row with some subrow,,,

Answer (score 0):

you can use DataGrid Component from Mui v5 and then use `renderCell` method for that specific row so you can let 2 or more data with the same key can combine